# In Node.js, how can I do nested callbacks with node-seq

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am working with the node-seq module by @substack, but hit a little bump.

What I want to do is: 2 parallel asynchronous actions, that each do something to their result, and then once both are complete they send their modified result to a finishing action.

After some tinkering, I got this code to basically work:

```
var Seq = require('seq');


Seq()
    .par(function () {
        console.log('starting action 1');
        var self = this;
        someModule.someAsyncMethod(function(result) {
            // do some stuff with result
            console.log('finishing action 1');
            self(result);
        });
    })
    .par(function () {
        console.log('starting action 2');
        var self = this;        
        someModule.someAsyncMethod(function(result) {
            // do some stuff with result
            console.log('finishing action 2');
            self(result);
        }); 
    })
    .seq(function(result1, result2) {
        console.log('all actions done');
    });
;
```

The problem is, self(result) is sending the result to the console.log. I've read through the documentation but don't understand why this is.

My questions are:

1) Is there a way to turn off this logging behavior of self(result) ?

2) Is there a better way to do this?

thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should do `self(null, result)`.  Typical callbacks take error as the first argument, and result as the second.

Also, I think your final .seq would take a results array rather than `result1, result2`.  Check out http://substack.net/seq

Try:

```
Seq()
    .par(function () {
        console.log('starting action 1');
        var self = this;
        someModule.someAsyncMethod(function(result) {
            // do some stuff with result
            console.log('finishing action 1');
            self(null, result);
        });
    })
    .par(function () {
        console.log('starting action 2');
        var self = this;        
        someModule.someAsyncMethod(function(result) {
            // do some stuff with result
            console.log('finishing action 2');
            self(null, result);
        }); 
    })
    .seq(function(result1, result2) {
        console.log('all actions done');
    });
;
```

Comment: Yep, that worked! Thanks so much. That link was very helpful too. But here's a followup question: what if I don't need to do the "do some stuff with result" part. Is there a simpler way to write this that doesn't require the "var self = this" ?

Comment: Just a quick followup - this solved my problem, however it does pass in results1, results2 as separate objects instead of an array. Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: Thanks for your comments and feedback.  I misread the code from the link and updated my answer.  I think you still need to inform the `self(result)` to indicate that the function is done.  You can just do a noop in your final seq call.